# Hibernate Tools - Eclipse Luna Reverse Engineer Error - NoClassDefFoundError: org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.OverrideRepository

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, hibernate-tools

I get the following error in `Eclipse Luna` using the latest `Hibernate-tools` to attempt to reverse engineer my tables into Hibernate objects. I'm using `JDK 8` to run `Eclipse, 1.8` as my compliance levels and I've tried 1.7 and still the same error. I tried just removing all jars from my project `classpath` and same error. IT has something to do with the plugin I suspect. Does anyone know of a hack or quickfix?

```
org.hibernate.console.HibernateConsoleRuntimeException: Received a NoClassDefFoundError, probably the console configuration classpath is incomplete or contains conflicting versions of the same class
Received a NoClassDefFoundError, probably the console configuration classpath is incomplete or contains conflicting versions of the same class
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.OverrideRepository
Could not initialize class org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.OverrideRepository
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class   org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.OverrideRepository
Could not initialize class org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.OverrideRepository
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install the previous, stable, Kepler edition of the Hibernate tools, and then also install the Luna edition without uninstalling the Kepler version?

Is there a hibernate3.jar transitively added to the classpath by any maven enabled projects (check the effective pom.xml)?

You can check the plugins folder for eclipse to see if the latest Hibernate tools in fact is missing the `org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.OverrideRepository` class.  It is a nightly/unstable build, so that is entirely possible.

Lastly, you can remove Eclipse from the picture for debugging purposes by following the examples [in the hibernate docs](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/ant.html) to create an ant build file, and execute it from the commandline.  Using that approach, I was never able to accomplish anything useful, but I was able to identify what my particular problems were.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Hibernate-3.6.4 libraries. so I have configured Hibernate Console configuration as the Hibernate Version: 3.6 but its not worked for me. Then I googled and found something like I have to add some other libraries and I have to reduce some libraries. then nothing helped me.

Then I have changed the Hibernate Version as 3.6 to 3.5 in Hibernate Console configuration then it worked for me. Bingo!

[suggestion] -> before dealing with libraries just try something with Hibernate version.